# Modo verbal con "por poco que"

Tags: subjuntivo

Mi libro de gramática española (de los autores no hispanohablantes) dice que en las construcciones concesivas con “**por poco que**” se usa SIEMPRE el subjuntivo. He consultado el apartado 47.15 de NGLE y no dice nada de que el subjuntivo sea el único modo en dichas construcciones. Ahora me pregunto si es verdad y si se usa exclusivamente el modo subjuntivo (porque tal vez se trata de algo hipotético) o si hay también oraciones factuales con “por poco que” + indicativo (como con „por mucho que“ / „por más que“). ¿Me podríais ayudar?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(La pregunta es muy buena, pero la próxima vez sería bueno que incluyas ejemplos.)

Coincido con tu libro de gramática española. "por poco que" y "por mucho/más que" son equiparables a "no importa cuán poco" y "no importa cuánto", respectivamente. El verbo debe ir en subjuntivo porque la acción o estado en cuestión es desconocido o indeterminado, y esto nos aleja del uso del modo indicativo, utilizado para lo que constituye un hecho o una realidad.

Curiosamente, si se agrega el artículo neutro "lo" luego de "por", la construcción deja su sentido hipotético y adquiere un significado fáctico, que justifica el uso del indicativo. Comparemos:

1) **Por poco que estudies** , pasarás el examen. Es muy fácil. (= No importa cuán poco/Independientemente de cuán poco estudies, pasarás el examen.)

2) **Por lo poco que estudias** , es un milagro que hayas pasado el examen. (= Considerando lo poco que estudias / Puesto/Dado que estudias poco, es un milagro que hayas pasado el examen.)

3) **Por más/mucho que estudies** , no pasarás el examen. Es muy difícil. (= No importa cuánto estudies/Independientemente de cuánto estudies, no pasarás el examen.)

4) **Por lo mucho que estudias** , deberías pasar el examen. (= Considerando lo mucho que estudias / Puesto/Dado que estudias mucho, deberías pasar el examen.)

Las subordinadas en (1) y (3) son claramente concesivas. (2) y (4) tienen significado causal.

Comment: Sólo aclararía que (por lo menos para mí) hay una leve diferencia entre *por más que* y *por mucho que*. La segunda refiere a cantidad, la primera a si la acción fuese realizada o no: *Por más que estudies…* = *No importa si estudias o no…*. Y en este caso también vale decir simplemente *Estudies o no…*.

Comment: @pablodf76 Es verdad, Pablo. Tanto es así que bien se podría decir: "Por más que estudies mucho..." sin que sea redundante.